# Where can a where clause be added to a dynamic query with a cross apply?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query which takes a table, with a column that has a semi-colon delimited strings and separates it into columns:

```
DECLARE @NumWords INT

SELECT @NumWords = ISNULL(MAX((LEN(String) - LEN(REPLACE(String,';','')))/1 + 1), 0)
FROM
#TblName

DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = '
SELECT
t.Id
,t.String
,c.*
FROM
#TblName t 
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT

      '
WHILE @i <= @NumWords
BEGIN
SET @SQL = @SQL
         + IIF(@i > 1,', ','')
         + 'Column' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '1 = x.value (''/x[' + CAST(@I AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ']'',''varchar(max)'')'

SET @i = @i + 1
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + '
   FROM
      (SELECT CAST(''<x>'' + REPLACE(String,'';'',''</x><x>'') + ''</x>'' as XML) x) a
) c'

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Lets say I want to turn this into a stored procedure that let me query data from a column named "TableId."

How would I change this query so that I can execute that procedure with different values for "TableId"?

Current table:

[image]

Desired results:

[image]

Comment: Is there a max number of columns or do you really need to go dynamic

Comment: There is not a max number of columns. It can range from one to theoretically infinity but most likely will only go up to 5-7 max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick non-dynamic version.  The Dynamic will come in a moment

This is based off your earlier question.

You'll see that I currently have 9 poistions... easy to expand or contract.

```
Select A.ID
      ,A.SubNumber
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
                 From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select A.[Values] as [*] For XML Path('')),';','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

Returns

[image]

> **EDIT - Dynamic Version**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Col) 
                                   From (Select Top (Select Max(Len([Values])-Len(Replace([Values],';','')))+1 From YourTable) Col=Row_Number() Over (Order By Number) From master..spt_values ) A
                                   Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Id],[SubNumber],' + @SQL + '
  From (
        Select A.ID
              ,A.SubNumber
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (    
                         Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                               ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value(''(./text())[1]'', ''varchar(max)'')))
                         From  (Select x = Cast(''<x>''+ replace((Select A.[Values] as [*] For XML Path('''')),'';'',''</x><x>'')+''</x>'' as xml).query(''.'')) as A 
                         Cross Apply x.nodes(''x'') AS B(i) 
                     ) B

       ) A
 Pivot (max(RetVal) For [RetSeq] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

[image]

---

> **If it Helps the DYNAMIC SQL looks like this**

```
 Select [Id],[SubNumber],[1],[2],[3],[4]
  From (
        Select A.ID
              ,A.SubNumber
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (    
                         Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                               ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                         From  (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ replace((Select A.[Values] as [*] For XML Path('')),';','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                         Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i) 
                     ) B

       ) A
 Pivot (max(RetVal) For [RetSeq] in ([1],[2],[3],[4]) ) p
```

> **EDIT 2**

Your life will be much easier with a good parse/split function.  The Dynamic version would be dramatically simplified if you can use a TVF (Table-Valued-Function).

The UDF if interested

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ replace((Select @String as [*] For XML Path('')),@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

> **EDIT - 3**

```
Declare @Fetch int = 1

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Col) 
                                   From (Select Top (Select Max(Len([RowValues])-Len(Replace([RowValues],';','')))+1 From YourTable Where SequenceID=@Fetch) Col=Row_Number() Over (Order By Number) From master..spt_values ) A
                                   Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Id],[SubNumber],[SequenceID],' + @SQL + '
  From (
        Select A.ID
              ,SubNumber = Dense_Rank() over (Order by ID)
              ,A.SequenceID
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (    
                         Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                               ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value(''(./text())[1]'', ''varchar(max)'')))
                         From  (Select x = Cast(''<x>''+ replace((Select A.[RowValues] as [*] For XML Path('''')),'';'',''</x><x>'')+''</x>'' as xml).query(''.'')) as A 
                         Cross Apply x.nodes(''x'') AS B(i) 
                     ) B
         Where SequenceID = '+cast(@Fetch as varchar(25))+'

       ) A
 Pivot (max(RetVal) For [RetSeq] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p
 Order By 1'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Hi John, Sorry for such a late reply. This looks and works great. And I guess I could of cleared up my question a little better. Lets say that the rows have an extra column "SequenceId". So in the 3 rows you have the "SeuquenceId" is 0 and in the next row it changes but I want to grab these 3 rows by the sequence Id in a stored procedure or possibly the next seqeunce if I choose that. Is this possible?

Comment: @user3654442 I would need a better visual.  Could you edit your question and provide some sample data with desired results ?

Comment: Hi @John Cappelletti I added two images that show what I'm trying to do. Let me know if I should add more to it. The desired results table doesn't include anything that doesn't have a sequence Id of 1.

Comment: @user3654442 are you using the dynamic version?

Comment: Yeah this is with the dynamic.I used your first dynamic version to create the desired results table. Just cut off the last row that had the other sequence in it.

Comment: @user3654442 See Edit - 3 .  We use a Dense_Rank() to generate the SubNumber.   Apologies for the delay, my internet has been going up and down.

Comment: Hi John, is there no way to edit this so that it can be a stored procedure that I pass in the sequence Id to get just the rows with a sequence id of 1 or a different sequence Id if I choose to?  I don't see that possible yet in edit 3.

Comment: @user3654442 See Updated Edit-3 .  where just added a WHERE in the cols and Pivot  .  Currently we are getting (at)Fetch, but this can be a range if you like

Comment: Hey John, if I input a sequence number that doesn't exist I get an error that the top of fetch value is invalid. And I assume that's due to a null value. So I tried to put an ISNULL in there but that doesn't seem to fix this.  How would I handle the case of someone throwing in a sequence id that doesn't exist?